# Reference for all "about"/"chrome" address bar strings for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

It there a reference for all the magic strings which one can type on Google Chrome and Firefox?

For instance I forgot how to create/show profiles in Chrome beta. I later found that it was `about:flags`. I am sure I can find more magic strings if I were to sift through code or plough through documentation.

But any reference here would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: "[complete list of Chrome URLs](http://otaqui.com/blog/539/complete-list-of-special-google-chrome-urls/)".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Google Chrome

In Google Chrome, it's either of these:

- `about:about`
- `chrome://chrome-urls`

The page will list all possible pages. In Chrome, all `about:` pages are internally treated as Chrome URLs, with the `chrome://` protocol handler. Therefore, these are equivalent.

```
chrome://accessibility
chrome://appcache-internals
chrome://apps
chrome://blob-internals
chrome://bookmarks
chrome://cache
chrome://chrome
chrome://chrome-urls
chrome://components
chrome://copresence
chrome://crashes
chrome://credits
chrome://device-log
chrome://devices
chrome://dns
chrome://downloads
chrome://extensions
chrome://flags
chrome://flash
chrome://gcm-internals
chrome://gpu
chrome://help
chrome://histograms
chrome://history
chrome://indexeddb-internals
chrome://inspect
chrome://invalidations
chrome://linux-proxy-config
chrome://local-state
chrome://media-internals
chrome://memory
chrome://memory-internals
chrome://nacl
chrome://net-internals
chrome://newtab
chrome://omnibox
chrome://password-manager-internals
chrome://plugins
chrome://policy
chrome://predictors
chrome://print
chrome://profiler
chrome://quota-internals
chrome://sandbox
chrome://serviceworker-internals
chrome://settings
chrome://signin-internals
chrome://suggestions
chrome://sync-internals
chrome://system
chrome://terms
chrome://thumbnails
chrome://tracing
chrome://translate-internals
chrome://user-actions
chrome://version
chrome://view-http-cache
chrome://voicesearch
chrome://webrtc-internals
chrome://webrtc-logs
```

The following URLs are sectioned off because they cause something "bad" to happen:

```
chrome://badcastcrash
chrome://crash
chrome://crashdump
chrome://kill
chrome://hang
chrome://shorthang
chrome://gpuclean
chrome://gpucrash
chrome://gpuhang
chrome://ppapiflashcrash
chrome://ppapiflashhang
chrome://quit/
chrome://restart/
```

Last Updated: Chrome 46

### Mozilla Firefox

Mozilla Firefox has the same meta-page: `about:about`, but [here's a list](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About_protocol_links) as well:

```
about:about
about:accounts
about:addons
about:app-manager
about:buildconfig
about:cache
about:config
about:crashes
about:credits
about:customizing
about:downloads
about:healthreport
about:home
about:license
about:logo
about:memory
about:mozilla
about:networking
about:newtab
about:performance
about:permissions
about:plugins
about:preferences
about:privatebrowsing
about:rights
about:robots
about:serviceworkers
about:sessionrestore
about:startpage
about:support
about:sync-log
about:sync-progress
about:sync-tabs
about:telemetry
about:webrtc
about:welcomeback
```

Last Updated: Firefox 40.0.3 canonical-1.0

Answer (score 3):

Just enter this in your chrome browser for a complete list:

```
chrome://chrome-urls/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most exhaustive list out there, but it expands the list you gave us:

```
about:blank – the empty page
about:cache – disk and memory cache information
about:net-internals – network information including Proxy, HostResolver, URLRequest, HTTPCache and SocketStream
about:crash – the page shown when a tab process crashes
about:credits – list of libraries and other code used in Chrome, with links
about:hang – this seems to kill a tab for me (I haven’t linked for that reason – use at your own risk)
about:memory – memory usage of the various processes
about:shorthang – see about:hang above
about:terms – Google Chrome Terms of Service
about:inducebrowsercrashforrealz – not many lolz here
chrome://extensions/ – installed extensions
chrome://history/ – your browsing history
chrome://newtab – the new tab page
chrome://thumb/http://www.google.com/ – thumbnail for a page you’ve visited
chrome://favicon/http://www.google.com/ – favicon for a page you’ve visited
view-source:http://www.santiagolizardo.com – view the source of a web page
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/url_constants.cc
or http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/url_constants.cc for the complete listing of Chromium `chrome://...` URLs.