# What are all the about: pages of Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, about-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference for all “about”/“chrome” address bar strings for Firefox and Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/324287/reference-for-all-about-chrome-address-bar-strings-for-firefox-and-chrome)

I know **about:home**, **about:robots**, **about:config** and some others, but is there somewhere a list of ALL about: pages of Firefox? I googled but didn´t find something.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reference for all “about”/“chrome” address bar strings for Firefox and Chrome](http://superuser.com/q/324287/108226)

Comment: [Firefox docs on the about protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/The_about_protocol)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can view all the Mozilla Firefox `about:` pages by typing this in the address bar:

```
about:about
```

You’ll be presented with a hyperlink to every usable `about:` page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia: [about URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme)

> **about:about:**
>  Shows all about links.
>
> ---
>
> **about:bloat:**
>       Displays BloatView output (disabled in release builds). Superseded by about:memory on Gecko 1.9.2[6]
>
> ---
>
> **about:blocked:**
>         Shows the malware protection page used when the browser identifies a page as not safe for viewing. Firefox 3+
>
> ---
>
> **about:addons:**
>      Shows installed addons, plugins, themes, and provides an interface for installing new addons. Firefox 4+, SeaMonkey
>   2.1+
>
> ---
>
> **about:buildconfig:**
>     Shows the arguments and options used to compile the build in use
>
> ---
>
> **about:cache:**
>       Shows information about the Cache Service. Number of entries, location of cache, size of cache, etc. for both
>   memory and disk cache.
>
> ---
>
> **about:cache?device=memory:**
>     Shows individual entries in memory
>
> ---
>
> **about:cache?device=disk:**
>       Shows individual entries on disk
>
> ---
>
> **about:cache?device=offline:**
>    Shows individual entries for offline viewing. Gecko 1.9+
>
> ---
>
> **about:cache-entry:**
>     Shows information about a cache entry. Used in about:cache links. Requires parameters.
>
> ---
>
> **about:certerror:**
>       Shows the error page used when an SSL/TLS certificate is untrusted or otherwise invalid.
>
> ---
>
> **about:config:**
>      Shows an interface for viewing and setting a wide variety of configuration variables, many of which are not
>   otherwise accessible through the GUI (options panels)
>
> ---
>
> **about:crashes:**
>     Shows details of crashes submitted by Mozilla's crash reporter. Firefox 3+, SeaMonkey 2.0+
>
> ---
>
> **about:credits:**
>     Shows a list of all those who contributed to Mozilla
>
> ---
>
> **about:feeds:**
>       Shows the page used when clicking the rss feed icon in the address bar.
>
> ---
>
> **about:home:**
>        Shows the Firefox 4 default home page.
>
> ---
>
> **about:jetpack:**
>         Shows an interface for viewing and setting the JetPack extension
>
> ---
>
> **about:license:**
>   but with all occurrences of license used as a noun replaced with licence (see American and British English spelling
>   differences). Not available in Firefox 4
>
> ---
>
> **about:logo:**
>    Shows the logo used on the about: screen
>
> ---
>
> **about:memory:**
>      Shows memory usage. Firefox 3.6+
>
> ---
>
> **about:mozilla:**
>     Easter egg: Shows a verse from The Book of Mozilla
>
> ---
>
> **about:neterror:**
>    Shows the error page used when the browser could not access the requested path.
>
> ---
>
> **about:newtab:**
>      Shows a grid of your favorite and most-visited websites, Firefox 13+.
>
> ---
>
> **about:permissions:**
>         Shows permissions for sites on Firefox 6.0a1.
>
> ---
>
> **about:plugins:**
>     Shows installed, currently enabled plug-ins.
>
> ---
>
> **about:privatebrowsing:**
>         Can be used to switch to private browsing mode, shows a message indicating that Firefox will not
>   remember any history for the current session. Note: It does not show
>   URI on the address bar.
>
> ---
>
> **about:rights:**
>      Shows licensing information.
>
> ---
>
> **about:robots:**
>          Easter egg, beginning with March 8, 2008 trunk builds. The title of a window contains a citation from The Day
>   the Earth Stood Still.[7]
>
> ---
>
> **about:sessionrestore:**
>      Shows an interface for viewing about last session
>
> ---
>
> **about:support:**
>     Shows troubleshooting information. Firefox 3.6+, SeaMonkey 2.1+
>
> ---
>
> **about:sync-tabs:**
>       Shows list of tabs from other computers. Requires enabled synchronisation.

Comment: You missed some parts of the text while copypasting.